# How to check if at least one of the two columns are filled with data?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table to hold phrases with their translation and pronunciation.

I'm not interested in providing a `translation` (that's why I removed NOT NULL on the translation column) but I want to provide a `pronunciation` for all inserts.

```
CREATE TABLE phrase (
    id SERIAL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    phrase TEXT NOT NULL,
    translation TEXT,
    pronunciation TEXT,
    created timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    modified timestamptz,
);
```

However other users may want to add a `translation` but not a `pronunciation` or they want to fill both columns with data. It's up to them.

However I want at least one of the columns to be provided.

"No matter what you provide user, a `translation` or a `pronunciation`, at least provide one of the two. If both are empty, then no inserts. If one of them is filled, then perform insert."

I can do this checking and validation on the server-side with PHP but I was thinking if it would be better to check on the database-side as well. I read something about this:

```
constraint chk_fields check (translation is not null or pronunciation is not null)
```

but I have no idea where to add it in the `CREATE TABLE` statement. I can re-create the whole table, that's not an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add it as another "list item" if you want to call it like that.

```
CREATE TABLE phrase (
    id SERIAL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    phrase TEXT NOT NULL,
    translation TEXT,
    pronunciation TEXT,
    created timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    modified timestamptz,
    constraint chk_fields check (translation is not null or  pronunciation is not null)
);
```

You can also use an `ALTER TABLE` statement to add the constraint to the existing table.

```
ALTER TABLE phrase
            ADD CONSTRAINT chk_fields
                           CHECK (translation IS NOT NULL
                                   OR pronunciation IS NOT NULL);
```

(The data must already meet the requirements.)